# visual studio won't auto implement interface

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

The normal blue underline bar isn't showing up to auto implement all MustOverride methods inside and abstract class in vb.net. I've imported what I needed to but the option doesn't exist. Any ideas why not? Hovering over the class name gives me all of the methods that I must inherit.
 [image: Screen Shot]

Comment: There is no evidence that you try to implement an interface, that requires the Implements keyword.

Comment: To follow what @HansPassant said, in addition `MembershipProvider` is a class, not an interface, and classes can't be implemented (at least in the implement an interface sense).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just that you are using the `Inherits` keyword when you wanted to use the `Implements` keyword.

[image: Implement Interface]

Also, it is a standard convention to start the names of your Interfaces with a capital I. So your code should instead look like:

```
Public Class AshleyMembershipProvider
    Implements IMembershipProvider

End Class
```

Comment: @dko, If this has resolved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as the answer :)